# What is a TLS Lenovo Home automation controller?

Tags: security, device-manager

I went to install a printer on my laptop and spotted the following:

[image: Device manager screenshot: Lonovo Home automation controller 1-00-00 LnvCon 1.0]

I have an HP laptop and am in the office and don't have anything Lenovo related hooked up to my machine, so what could this be?

Comment: whats in the hardware and upnp tabs?

Answer (score 1):

I've found it on a Lenovo E550 notebook, the only Lenovo product in my lan.
I don't know what it is, but I got rid of it by uninstalling Lenovo Peer Connect and Lenovo Communications Utility.